# how to watermark a photo using wand in python?

Tags: imagemagick, wand

how to convert this command to python using wand ?

```
composite -dissolve 30% -gravity south output-file.png input-file.jpg watermark.jpg
```

(this command adds a watermark to a photo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the expected result, I would assume you would want to [composite](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite_channel) with a [dissolve operator](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.COMPOSITE_OPERATORS). You can use [Image.transparentize](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.transparentize) to adjust the watermark before applying the composite.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.compat import nested

images = (
  'rose.png',
  'wizard.png'
)

with nested(Image(filename=images[0]),
            Image(filename=images[1])) as (rose, wizard):
  rose.transparentize(0.33)
  wizard.composite_channel("all_channels",
                           rose,
                           "dissolve",
                           wizard.width/2 - rose.width/2,
                           wizard.height - rose.height)
  wizard.save(filename='out.png')
```

[image: how to watermark a photo]

*hint:* Adjust the [channel argument](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/wand/image.html#wand.image.CHANNELS) for greater control & effects.